# I want to implement picture-in-picture function with ffmpeg, can anyone help me?

Tags: ffmpeg

in ffmpeg command, it's very simple:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -i timer.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]crop=w=160:h=110:x=650:y=300[timer4.mp4]; [timer4.mp4]scale=30:30[timer-30m30.mp4]; [0][timer-30m30.mp4]overlay=W-w:10" output-video-overlay.mp4
```

but now I need to implement with the ffmpeg api, I have searched all day, but still not found any useful impormation, can any one help me? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really "an API" to do this. It is a few dozen lines of code. ffmpeg supplies examples fo how to use the filter graph in the examples folder included in the source code.

see: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering_video.c